# Implementing html from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, velocity.js

I was watching a tutorial / demo of velocity.js which was being used to simulate a dynamic 3d view on a website:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDLiVB6g2NY&hd=1

It's very similar to a task I've been given and I understand it logically but I don't understand what I need to do to implement the following code in html. I know I need an element with id="count" to receive the DOM dot elements but I'm not sure what kind of element that should be or what other parameters it would need or additional code. I have a .dot class in my CSS and I can manipulate it with velocity.js it's just a matter of instantiating them as he shows in the video.

```
var isWebkit =  /Webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
    isChrome =  /Chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
    isMobile =  !!("ontouchstart" in window),
    isAndroid = /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

$.fn.velocity.defaults.easing = "easeInOutSine";

function r(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min +1)) +min;
}

var dotsCount = isMobile ? (isAndroid ? 40 : 70) : (isChrome ? 200 : 125),
    dotsHtml = "",
    $count = $("#count"),
    $dots;

//instantite DOM elements
for(var i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++){
    dotsHtml += "<div class = 'dot'></div>";
}
$dots = $(dotsHtml);
$count.html(dotsHtml);
```

any help and advice will be appreciated so much.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I don't know where the extra came from.

Comment: $count's html is being set: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your html should look like according to the instructions given in the video.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="description"></div>
     <div id="count">

      </div>
</div>
```

The dots will be auto generated into $('#count') . The rest of the code in the video controls the dot/container animation by altering the perspective of the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

This will repair your code:

`isMobile` is not initialised

```
 var dotsCount = 15;//isMobile ? (isAndroid ? 40 : 70) : (isChrome ? 200 : 125),
    var $dots = 0;
        dotsHtml = "",
        $count = $("#count"),
        $dots = 0;

    //instantite DOM elements
    for (var i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
         dotsHtml += "<div class = 'dot'></div>";
    }
    $dots = $(dotsHtml);
    $count.html(dotsHtml);

    function r(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpncxmf0/

Comment: sorry I should've made it more clear, it is included, I just took a snippet of the most relevant bit... I'll amend the question.

Comment: @AlecGamble please also look at the fiddle and open your console and look at the html. the code works!

Comment: but what do I need to do next to make a visual representation like the example? like I have a small amount of CSS indicating what a 'dot' should look like but I don't know what the container for the $count reference should be like to achieve this. I mean my guess would've just been a div with 100% width and height and a background colour but I can't get it to instantiate the 'dot' elements... it works if i put them in manually but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm not trying to be awkward btw, I just don't understand :(

Comment: As stated in the video you have to link velocity.js for this code to work . Also the .dots are just style with 50% border-radius and drop shadow .

Comment: You're right it does work, it was something in my animation code that was broken and I was panicking. Thank you for your help.

also thank you Kp - I did have a link to it in the html, do you mean box shadow?